# How to check if sync adapter is running and the interval at which it is scheduled, using adb shell?

Tags: android, synchronization, adb, android-syncadapter

I would like to know if there is a way to list the syncs that are currently active for an android app and where does android store the interval at which these syncs are scheduled?

I want to get this information using `adb shell`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
adb shell dumpsys content
```

You should see a lot of information, here's just a small snippet:

```
data connected: true
auto sync: u0=true 
memory low: false
device idle: false
reported active: false
accounts: 2
now: 11375038 (2019-07-19 14:02:17)
uptime: 3h09m35s
time spent syncing: 2m55s, sync not in progress

Active Syncs: 0

Pending Syncs: 0

Periodic Syncs: 22
JobId=104677 MyAccount | email@email.com/com.myaccount u0 [com.myprovider] PERIODIC Reason=Periodic (period=7h45m54s flex=18m38s) Owner={u0a92 com.myapp}

Sync Status
Account MyAccount | email@email.com u0 com.myaccount
=======================================================================
Authority                       Syncable  Enabled  Delay  Loc  Poll  Per  Serv  User  Tot  Time    Last Sync            Backoff  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.myprovider                  1         true            0    1     26   3     44    74   35m43s  USER SUCCESS           
                                                                                                   2019-07-19 13:53:48
```